# If A is an array of type int, what command would you use to put the value 50 in the first position of the array

Tags: java

If A is an array of type int, what command would you use to put the value 50 in the first position of the array

Comment: maybe [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) tutorial (and others linked  on this official Oracle page)

Answer (score 1):

```
A[0] = 50;
```

This will store 50 in the first element of A.

Answer (score 1):

`A[0] = 50;` This assign first element to 50.
There is a lot of resource about java array online, i think all the basic tutorial would cover about this.